# Wampserver MySQL InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I downloaded wampserver on windows10 x64 running on mac bootcamp but i could not start the mysql service. The wamp icon always orange and apche service is running. I check the mysql log and get this:

```
2017-06-16T05:51:21.806982Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Header page consists of zero bytes in datafile: .\ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 0. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-16T05:51:21.806982Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile '.\ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2017-06-16T05:51:21.806982Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile '.\ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2017-06-16T05:51:21.806982Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption                                                                                                                                                    
2017-06-16T05:51:22.144508Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-06-16T05:51:22.144508Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-06-16T05:51:22.144508Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: duplicate of : https://serverfault.com/questions/104014/innodb-error-log-file-ib-logfile0-is-of-different-size . Basically deleting both ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 should solve it.

Comment: @PrabhatG I tried that but the error still same

Comment: You have a MAC, why not use the Apache/MySQL/PHP that you install on the Mac as native

Comment: Alternatively, did you install WAMPServer from a Windows Admin account?